# Get image path prestashop 1.5

Tags: prestashop

need your help! How can I get the path to the image with the product ID?

Link :: getImageLink () - the first parameter of $ name, I do not know?

```
$searchResults = Search::find((int)(Tools::getValue('id_lang')), $query, 1, 10, 'position', 'desc', true);
foreach ($searchResults as &$product)
{
    $product['product_link'] = $this->context->link->getProductLink($product['id_product'], $product['prewrite'], $product['crewrite']);
    $imageid = Product::getCover($product['id_product']);
    // there i have image ID, how get image path $imagepath?
    $product['image'] = $imagepath;
}
die(Tools::jsonEncode($searchResults));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `Link::getImageLink()`. This is the method you have to use to have the url of a product's image.

```
$imagePath = Link::getImageLink($product['link_rewrite'], $product['id_product'], 'home_default'); // change the last parameters to get the size you need
```

This method is also available in the template if you need it with the same syntax

```
{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_product, 'home_default')}`
```

**EDIT**
I re-read your question and realized you knew that. So yeah the first parameter is the 
`link_rewrite`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To get product image properly follow below code & pass parameters properly (If you follow this code, you will not get problem when URL rewrite is enabled).

```
{$link->getImageLink($name, $ids, $type = NULL) }
```

details of parameters are like

```
@param string $name rewrite link of the image
@param string $ids id part of the image filename - can be "id_product-id_image" (legacy support, recommended) or "id_image" (new)
@param string $type
```

Example for you

```
<img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $image.id_image, 'large_default')}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: If you have the id_product, write a function that gets you the id_image attribute like this:

```
private static function getCover($product_id) {
  $sql = 'SELECT id_image FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'image WHERE cover = 1 AND   id_product='.$product_id;
  $result = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql);
  return $result['id_image'];
}
```

STEP 2: Then get the image path with a code like this:

```
$id_image = self::getCover($product['id_product']);
$image_path = $id_image.'-home_default/'.$product['link_rewrite'].'.jpg';
```

NB: $product is a an array gotten from executing an sql statement